# Finger Exercise: Update book cipher by creating new book

Tags: python, programming-challenge, hash-map, lambda

I'm working my way through the finger exercises in John Guttag's book Introduction to Python Programming, third edition. The following finger exercise on page 143 describes encryption/decryption with a book cipher. The first exercise was to implement `decoder` and `decrypt` in the same style as encryption is working.

The book mentions this bug and gives the task to implement a solution like they hinted at:

> **The bug:**
>
> When a character occurs in `plain text` but not in the `book`,
> something bad happens. The `code_keys` dictionary assigns `-1` to
> each such character, and `decode_keys` assigns `-1` to the last
> character in the book, whatever that may be.
>
> **The solution:**
>
> Create a new book by appending something to the original book.

My solution `new_book` uses a lambda function to be in line with the rest of the code. But this overturns the principle of encryption, if the plain text is needed during encryption and decryption

```py
# Mapping individual, unique letters of plaintext to index number
gen_code_keys = (lambda book, plain_text:
                 {c: str(book.find(c)) for c in plain_text})

# Slicing operator at the end to remove the first '*' at the beginning
encoder = (lambda code_keys, plain_text:
           "".join(["*" + code_keys[c] for c in plain_text])[1:])

# Encrypt plain_text by giving the encoder a book for indexing
encrypt = (lambda book, plain_text:
           encoder(gen_code_keys(book, plain_text), plain_text))

# Decode key generator analogue to gen_code_keys
gen_decode_keys = (lambda book, cipher:
                   {c: book[int(c)] for c in cipher.split("*")})

# Implement decoder by looping through all numbers in cipher
decoder = (lambda decode_keys, cipher:
           "".join((decode_keys[c] for c in cipher.split("*"))))

# Decrypting the cipher analog to encrypt function
decrypt = (lambda book, cipher:
           decoder(gen_decode_keys(book, cipher), cipher))

Don_Quixote = "In a village of La Mancha, the name of which I have no " \
    "desire to call to mind, there lived not long since one of those " \
    "gentlemen that keep a lance in the lance-rack, an old buckler, a lean " \
    "hack, and a greyhound for coursing."

# --------------- My Solution --------------- #
# Creating new book with missing letters in book to fix cipher bug
new_book = (lambda book, plain_text:
            book + "".join([c for c in plain_text if c not in book]))

# plain text contains the letters: !ABENQjx
plain_text = "No joke, Abraham Boston had six beer. Everyone it Q!"

# Create new book by appending missing letter from plain_text
book = new_book(Don_Quixote, plain_text)

print(plain_text)
cipher = encrypt(book, plain_text)
print(cipher)
print(decrypt(book, cipher))
```

Ok, so I changed my code so far that I create the updated book with the missing characters appended before encrypting/decrypting. Thus I removed the function call `new_book` inside the `encrypt` and `decrypt` function. With that at least I don't need the `plain_text` in my `decrypt` function.

Are there further improvements I could make?

Comment: Just to be clear, the bug is in the original code that Guttag gives, and you are showing us your solution for that bug.  Is that correct?

Comment: You’ll need to rethink your fix.  If you and I agree on a book, and I send you an encrypted message, with characters that are not in the book, you won’t have my new book since it depends on the message I’m sending you, which I’ve only sent in encrypted form.  You can’t decode it without know a-priori what the message is.

Comment: @Teepeemm Exactly, the encryption implementation is given like this, the decryption is implemented by me.
The bug is pointed out in the book.

Comment: @AJNeufeld that exactly is my issue. The book cipher decides on a book before. But if I change the book i need to communicate it to the receiver

Comment: Your implementation requires a new book with each message.  The “book” should be agreed upon/exchanged through other means, not sent along with each and every encrypted message which is sent, as that totally breaks any resemblance of any security.  Hence, the “need to rethink your fix,”  such as (for example) by directly injecting the unencryptable characters directly in the cypher text: `N*34*123*j*…`  But then: what if you want to encrypt numbers, and your book doesn’t contain all of the digits?

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edits.  You cannot substantially modify your question after answers have been posted, as this can invalidate answers.  See “what can I do after someone answer my question” in the [help].  In particular, if you want to get further feedback on your new code, ask a new question.  If you just want to show your updated code, post your own answer to your question, however it must actually be formatted as if it was an answer, with additional insights & feedback.

Comment: Good to know. I wasn't sure if I should post it as its own reply. Hence the separator and edit note. As I don't have anything further to add, I leave it with your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer this question.  There is so much about the code I *hate*, but I have to restrict my review to only your code: the code after the `# —- My solution -- #` comment marker.

## Forget lambda

`lambda` functions have their uses.  This is not one of them.  Compare this:

```
new_book = (lambda book, plain_text:
            book + "".join([c for c in plain_text if c not in book]))
```

with this:

```
def new_book(book, plain_text):
    return book + "".join([c for c in plain_text if c not in book])
```

They both do exactly the same thing: they create a function accepting two parameters, and assign that function to the identifier `new_book`.  In my opinion, the latter is clearer; the reader can immediately tell a function is being defined.  The indentation is less, and a level of parentheses has been removed.

Additionally, several language features are available with the `def` version - type-hints and `"""docstrings"""` - which can further improve understandability.

```
def new_book(book: str, plain_text: str) -> str:
    """
    Create a new “book” to use for encryption and decryption,
    will is a duplicate of the original book, plus any letters
    in the `plain_text` message which are missing from the original
    book.
    """

    return book + "".join([c for c in plain_text if c not in book])
```

## O(mn)

Your book has a certain number of characters.  Let’s call that `m`.  Your `plain_text` has a certain number of characters.  Let’s call than `n`.

`[c for c in plain_text if c not in book]`

This loops `n` times, going through all of the letters of `plain_text`, and for each letter, it searches `book` for an occurrence of that letter.  If a letter is not found in `book`, that is only determined after scanning through all `m` letters of the book.  `n` outer loops iterations with up to `m` iterations in the inner loop means this is has a worst case of \$O(m*n)\$ operations.  Potentially quite slow!

This worse case bound can be improved, but it requires a bit of preprocessing … which is easy with the `def` version of the function:

```
def new_book(book, plain_text):
    book_letters = set(book)
    return book + "".join([c for c in plain_text if c not in book_letters])
```

Turning `book` into a `set` of letters is an \$O(m)\$ operation.  With that, `c not in book_letters` becomes an \$O(1)\$ operation.  Repeated in the loop `n` times makes it \$O(n)\$, so the entire function becomes \$O(m + n)\$ … considerably faster.

But wait!  While we’re at it, what is with the temporary list of characters `[c …]`?  It is created just to be iterated over in the `join(…)`.  Why not just iterate without the temporary list creation?

```
def new_book(book, plain_text):
    book_letters = set(book)
    return book + "".join(c for c in plain_text if c not in book_letters)
```

## Better solutions

Why add `plain_text` to the book?  If you and you friend (or spy) have exchanged a book, and then you need to send a message with letters which were not in the book, you have to send a complete `new_book` to your friend (spy) … which could be intercepted making the encryption useless.

Plus, if a second message is sent with still different letters, yet another book would be necessary.  A third message would require a third book, and so on!  Decoding the `cipher` would require knowing which `book` was used to encode it (book1, book2, book3, …) — information which is not given.

It is a simple matter to expand the book without relying on `plain_text`.  Just unconditionally add [`string.printable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable) to the original book.  This easily takes care of your missing `!ABENQjx` characters.

Except, it is still not a complete solution.  `Résumé` would still result in `-1` encodings.  Adding the entire Unicode character set to `book` would be required, if you stayed with this approach.  Instead, why not record the maximum value your book encoder returns, and return that value plus `ord(c)` for characters not in the book?  When an encoded value exceeds the maximum value the book can decode, subtract that maximum, and use `chr(#)` to convert it back to the required character.

Comment: Exclusive use of lambda functions I consider good only in this task as a restriction, otherwise I agree with you that the function definition is cleaner and much better.

Appending `string.printable` at the end didn't occur to me. At least that solves the problem for ascii characters.

Comment: By record the maximum value do you mean the max value found in the dictionary created by `gen_code_keys` for sending along or maybe attach to the cipher either at the beginning or at the end? Thus, requiring re-write of `encoder` and `decoder` to check of values of `-1` when encoding and values greater than max value when decoding.

Comment: Yes, sort of.  If you passed `book` as the `plain_text`  to `gen_code_keys`, there is a maximum value it can generate, which would be up to `len(book)`.   No, not for sending along or attaching to cypher.  Both sender and receiver have the book (singular), and can independently compute the value.